# What exactly is a shindig?

Tags: terminology

What exactly is a shindig?

I tried to translate it in Google Translate into spanish but it gave me two translations

- Fiesta (party)
- Pelea (fight)

So which one is it?

**Update**

The context I heard it on was a chapter of [The Firm](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1949012/), where a lawyer tells another one she hopes their "little shindig" didn't scare him off, or something like that. She was referring to a little event they held for their clients, where he was introduced to some other lawyers, who weren't particularly friendly with him.

Comment: Is there a difference? (-: But seriously, it means either *party* or *event* in the U.S. as well.

Answer (score 4):

From Merriam-Webster:

> **shindig**, *noun* :
>
> **1** : a festive occasion: as
>
> **a** : a social gathering often with dancing {every community has its weekly shindig in some farm home -- American Guide Series: Oklahoma}
>
> **b** : a usually large often overly lavish party {coming-out party ... was the gaudiest shindig since the war -- Time}
>
> **c** : an elaborate celebration often commemorating some special event and involving extensive planning {to mark the day with the
>   largest peacetime parade ... I had drawn the assignment of assembling
>   and staging this enormous shindig -- Frank Zachary}
>
> **2** : SHINDY **2** {touched off the whole bloody shindig that raged for years -- Alan Devoe}

...where *shindy* is defined as:

> **shindy**, *noun* :
>
> **1** : SHINDIG **1** {the summer tourist season ... is marked by galas, festivals, and other shindys -- Holiday}
>
> **2** : a general commotion : noisy row : FRACAS, UPROAR {created a shindy, saying that they were already an oppressed class --
>   F.A.Swinnerton} {it must look bad after that shindy I had with the
>   director -- C.D.Lewis}

I'm not sure that I have ever heard *shindig* used in the sense of *shindy* in the US.

Comment: +1: OED also confirms one sense of *shindig* as *shindy* (a row, commotion,). I don't think I've ever heard *shindy*, but I'm quite familiar with *shindig* to mean an altercation / fight. Usually in the sense of a mass public brawl (football hooligans, street gangs, etc., who probably see it as something of a party anyway).

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, at least, shindig almost always means party. It's colloquial and normally implies you know the host well, even if it's a formal event like their wedding. It's used in a similar way to "knees-up".

I've never heard shindig used to mean a fight.You may be getting confused with skirmish?

Comment: Agreed. (Fellow Brit here.)

Answer (score 0):

In the US, it's a lively party.

Answer (score 0):

**shindig** 
n. *informal* 1.
a large, lively party, esp. one celebrating something.

My online dictionary tags the word as "informal."  I thought that might be worth mentioning.

Also, given the context, I can understand why the word *shindig* would be used.  "*I hope our little party didn't scare you off,*" wouldn't sound quite right, nor would, "*I hope our little gala didn't scare you off.*"  By using a more informal word, the allusion to some possible improprieties at the event seems stronger. The writer may have even deliberately chosen a word phonetically similar to *shenanigans*, but I'm only surmising.